# Is it possible to replace all instance by using regex with VS code?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I have a json file, where I would like to update the numbers with quotes (""). I am trying with `regexp`, but  I am not able to get the result. Is it possible or `regex` only for search purpose?

Here is my try:

find: `phoneId:\s\d+`
replace: `phoneId: '/phoneId:\s\d+` - not working

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You have to use a capture group `(\d+)` for your number, so that you can use `phoneId: '$1'` in your replacement

Comment: read the RegEx pages on MDN, learn the syntax of regex just like you learn the syntax of C# or JavaScript or ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an online regex tester like [RegExr](https://regexr.com/71c3u) can help constructing regular expressions like this. Like @derpirscher already commented, you have to define a [capture group](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html) in your find regex using `(...)`, which then can be referenced in your replace regex using `$x` with x starting from 1.

In your case this would be:

Find: `phoneId: (\d+)`

Replace: `phoneId: "$1"`